Inconsistent result for NUMA node memory usage in SQL Server
Regarding the query below which I run on a physical server with SQL Server 2019:
SELECT
    memory_node_id,
    SUM(pages_kb) / 1024.0/1024 AS TotalMemoryGB
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
GROUP BY memory_node_id
ORDER BY memory_node_id;

for memory_node_id = 0 it shows more memory than physically available on the NUMA node. How can that be?


for memory_node_id = 0 it shows more memory than physically available on the NUMA node. How can that be?

You're looking at the memory from the clerk perspective and assuming all of the memory for the associated node is local memory which is an incorrect assumption. You'll need to check sys.dm_os_memory_nodes and look at the foreign committed memory to see how much is allocated from another node but charged to that specific node.
